# Angular Reactive Form mat-option to pass object

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have mat-option where I want to pass object instead of single value.

My component.ts

[image]

My html

[image]

The states is object that has property name and code.

For mat-option I am not exactly sure how to pull both name and code and insert those to my shippingForm as object.
Right now its only pulling single value of state.name.

Comment: you mean mat--option value as a object?

Comment: @Chellappan Yeah when I submit form and it goes to back end.  I want the state to contain object.  Not even sure if I am doing this correctly.

Comment: currently you are getting state,name only right?

Comment: @Chellappan Yeah.  I actually got rid of formbuildergroup for state and in html instead of [value]="state.name" I put [value]="state".  It started to add object with both values.  But getting [object, object] in the view.

Comment: Try to use {{object | json }}

Comment: Fixed a issue with using [displayWith] binding.

Answer (score 0):

[ReactuiveForms documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#introduction-to-reactive-forms) explains explicitly that you have 2 models

1. Model for form binding (form model)
2. Actual data model

You have to manually map form model into your data model.

In other words - you must take state name and code from the form, and create `State` obiect using those values.